# Specific Word Filter

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make this code find specific words instead of checking in between words ?

**Example**:
Filtrated word is d**k this code counted Dickinson as a bad word.

I want it to find specific words with its same functions like ( show + counting words in alert window )

```js
// Enter the words to be filtered in the line below:
var swear_words_arr=new Array("dick","bloody","war","terror");

var swear_alert_arr=new Array;
var swear_alert_count=0;
function reset_alert_count()
{
 swear_alert_count=0;
}
function validate_text()
{
 reset_alert_count();
 var compare_text=document.form1.text.value;
 for(var i=0; i<swear_words_arr.length; i++)
 {
  for(var j=0; j<(compare_text.length); j++)
  {
   if(swear_words_arr[i]==compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length)).toLowerCase())
   {
    swear_alert_arr[swear_alert_count]=compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length));
    swear_alert_count++;
   }
  }
 }
 var alert_text="";
 for(var k=1; k<=swear_alert_count; k++)
 {
  alert_text+="\n" + "(" + k + ")  " + swear_alert_arr[k-1];
 }
 if(swear_alert_count>0)
 {
  alert("The message will not be sent!!!\nThe following illegal words were found:\n_______________________________\n" + alert_text + "\n_______________________________");
  document.form1.text.select();
 }
 else
 {
  document.form1.submit();
 }
}
function select_area()
{
 document.form1.text.select();
}
window.onload=reset_alert_count;
```

```css
body
{
    background: #cbc3a6;
    color: #37445D;
    font: 15px/20px Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

#container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 550px;
}

textarea
{
    border: 2px solid #000;
    display: block;
    font: 14px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    resize: none;
    width: 500px;
}

input[type="button"]
{
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #000;
    display: table;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    width: 175px;
}

input[type="button"]:hover
{
    background-color: #666;
    background-image: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: table;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Bad Word Filter</h1>

<p>Disallows specific words to be sent in a form textarea.</p>
   Disallows specific words to be sent in a form textarea.

<p>Try entering the words "dick", "bloody", "war", or "terror" in the text box and click Submit.</p>

<div id="container">
    <form name="form1">
        <textarea rows="3" cols="40" name="text" placeholder="Enter one of the bad words above and then try submitting the form." onClick="select_area()"></textarea>

<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="validate_text();">
</form>
```

Comment: Use a regular expression with the `\b` word boundary pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing words in a text to see if they exist in your blocked list, okay, so in your code:

```
 if(swear_words_arr[i]==compare_text.substring(j, 
 (j+swear_words_arr[i].length)).toLowerCase())
  {
       swear_alert_arr[swear_alert_count]=compare_text.substring(j, 
          (j+swear_words_arr[i].length));
            swear_alert_count++;
  }
```

The sentences substring is being compared with the words in your list.

Instead, you can check if the blocked words exist in your sentence by using word boundary \b word \b:

Create a helper function to help you get match sentences, just pass in the text and the wordsList. Returns a list of matches.

```
function findWords (text, wordsList) {

  let metachars = /[(){[*+?.\\^$|]/g;

  for (var i = 0; i < wordsList.length; i++) {

     wordsList[i] = wordsList[i].replace(metachars, "\\$&");
   }

  let regex = new RegExp("\\b(?:" + wordsList.join("|") + ")\\b", "gi");

  return text.match(regex) || [];
}
```